# Download interrupted: bad record MAC android sdk

Tags: android, sdk

I try to install android sdk 5.1.1 on my computer, actually no sdk was installed and I got this error:

```
Preparing to install archives
Downloading SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2
Download interrupted: bad record MAC
Downloading Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19, revision 3
  Resuming Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19, revision 3 download at 14435181 (8%)
Download interrupted: bad record MAC
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

do you have any idea?

Comment: Google your error/search SO for it.

Comment: I tried this but I did not gget anything

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache(Android SDK Manager: Tools->Options). Force https to be fetched using http.